# Read in sensor Data (GPS raw Data) with adruino and store it on SD card

Tags: arduino, nmea

I want to read in GPS Data from a serial port of a ublox chip. I do not only want to read in NMEA sentences but also Raw data (Messages like MEASX, RAWX,SFRBX). If I simply connect my serial ports with a pc and read in the data with RealTerm (win) it works fine. However if I try to read in the data with adruino it reads in the NMEA sentences fine but it does not manage to read in the raw data correctely.

Here is the code I use:

```
String inData;

void setup() {
    Serial.begin(38400);
}

void loop() {
    while (Serial.available() > 0)
    {
        char recieved = Serial.read();
        inData += recieved; 

        // Process message when new line character is recieved
        if (recieved == '\n')
        {
            //Serial.print("Arduino Received: ");
            Serial.print(inData);

            inData = ""; // Clear recieved buffer
        }
    }

}
```

Any ideas how to simply read in a file line by line. I think the problem is i do not know how to handle the raw data - how to read that data in?

Best

[picture1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XWPXm.jpg)      [picture2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WOHaD.jpg)

Answer (score 4):

You don't need to check for CR, the GPS device sends the data in blocks, so if one block is done, the communication will be closed and the available()-statement will no longer be true.

```
if (gps.available())
{
    String Buffer = "";
    while (gps.available())
    {
        char GPSRX = gps.read();
        Buffer += GPSRX;

        //Serial.write(gps.read());
    }
    Serial.print(Buffer);
}
```

with 'gps' is an instance of SoftwareSerial:

```
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>    
SoftwareSerial gps(4, 3); // RX, TX

...

void setup()
{
    gps.begin(9600);
    ...
}

void loop()
{
    if (gps.available())
    {
        ...
    }

    ...
}
```